# How to add var javascript value into id name?

Tags: javascript

How to add var javascript value into id name ?

I have `$i = 5;` and `var i = 2;`

How to concatenate php var `$i` with javascript `var i` ?

I tried like this but not work.

```
$('#test<?PHP echo $i; ?>'+i).live('click', function() { 
do something
});
```

and

```
$('#test<?PHP echo $i; ?>'+i+'').live('click', function() { 
do something
});
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: `$('#test<?PHP echo $i; ?>'+i)` what it rendered?

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `live()` was deprecated in favour of `on()` years ago, you should update your jQuery.

Comment: Depending when this JS code runs, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) _might_ be relevant.

Comment: Any time you are generating ids in a loop for JS, you should probably be using a class instead.

Comment: Please show us what code was generated by each of your two fragments.

Answer (score 0):

```
var phpi = '<?PHP echo $i; ?>';
$('#test' + phpi + i).live('click', function() { 
    //do something
});
```

or if you want PHP $i + JS i for exmaple (3 + 2 = 5)

```
var phpi = <?PHP echo $i; ?>; // no quotes here as we need number
$('#test' + (phpi + i)).live('click', function() { 
    //do something
});
```

PHP echo makes some space so that might hamper the selector use it like this